# How can I stop my logo from stretching / being weird? (Blender 2.91.0)

Tags: vector

I'm new to blender (3 days) and I've recently tried to make some cosmetic packaging for a toothpaste brand.

I've been able to create the models to a decent extent, but when it comes to applying the logos, I am getting stretching and weird behaviour. I am planning on adding other parts of the packaging later, but before that, I need to understand how to fix this problem.

I'm using a png with no background, and I've tried to UV unwrap and map the textures on. I've attached the file and a screenshot below if that's any help at all.

Thanks for your help!
[image: Problem Screenshot]

Comment: The key is UVMap. How did you unwrapped your objects? How looks your UV Map? If you are not satisfied switch to UV Editing layout on top row and in edit mode reposition UVMap.

Answer (score -1):

I have seen your question and your issue, and It is quite common. Luckily, the solution is simple. Go to the UV editing section, before going there, remember to select the cylinder. Then select the face which is supposed to have the logo and carefully align it. For making it much more realistic, let the logo cover on of the faces but along with that, should cover a bit of the faces left and right to it. Hope it helps, if theres an issue with my solution, comment on my answer. I would also recommend going to this website to help you get started on stack exchange.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

and

https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour

Cheerios,
Aster17